# Problem with MEMCACHE and Redis with wp_options

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options, cache, code

I have developed a plugin for worpress but it is giving me problems when I start MEMCACHE o REDIS CACHE.

I have been told that the problem is that I am using **wp_options** directly and that I should replace it by accessing object cache through standard wordpress interfaces and not doing it directly.

so how should i do to override these wp_options methods to object cache interfaces?

```
add_option( $option, $value, $deprecated, $autoload);
delete_option( $option );
get_option( $option, $default = false );
update_option( $option, $newvalue, $autoload );
```

Thank you very much in advance and greetings

Comment: How are you currently using wp_options? What actual problems were you experiencing?

Comment: Who told you this? You are correct to use `get_option` etc, as a user of both Redis object cache dropins and memcached I and others use the options API on lots of enterprise grade sites that handle billions of page views, I would treat the advice you recieved with great suspicion, those _are_ the standard interfaces. Instead, ask about your problems, not how to implement the proposed solution (This is an X Y Problem)

Comment: i am getting 504 errors with my plugin when i turn on memcache